# Proftpd : login with filezilla fails when receiving map structure

Tags: ftp, debian-squeeze, proftpd

I setup a proftpd server, but I am running into an error when login in with filezilla

```
Commando:   PASV
Antwoord:   227 Entering Passive Mode (193,191,187,24,175,62).
Commando:   MLSD
Fout:   Verbinding verloren
Fout:   Ontvangen van mappenlijst is mislukt
```

It says connection lost and receiving directory listing has failed.

When I comment my TLS line it works, when I uncomment it I get the above.

My TLS configuration :

```
<IfModule mod_tls.c>
TLSEngine                  on
TLSLog                     /var/log/proftpd/tls.log
TLSProtocol                SSLv23
TLSOptions                 NoCertRequest
TLSRSACertificateFile      /etc/proftpd/ssl/proftpd.cert.pem
TLSRSACertificateKeyFile   /etc/proftpd/ssl/proftpd.key.pem
TLSVerifyClient            off
TLSRequired                on
</IfModule>
```

I can't seem to find anything abnormal after the authentication in my logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have a firewall? If so, you need to define a range of passive ports in proftpd and open them up in your firewall.

http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_PassivePorts.html